# PHP If/elseif/else for fetching and storing Select dropdown values

Tags: wordpress

I have created a conditional statement, which runs through different conditions based on which "value" the user has selected and submitted via the Submit button (Each condition contains a metakey which is then stored as apart of the user's data metakey within WordPress)

The issue I'm having is that only the first condition seems to be working in terms of the metakey stored, the "elseif" conditions aren't storing the value of the metakey when selecting other options within the dropdown.

Obviously I have done something wrong otherwise it would be working! But if anyone could assist me with showing me where I've gone wrong, that would be super helpful!

```
add_action( 'wppb_form_success', 'product_category_type', 20, 3 );
function select_choice_value( $http_request, $form_name, $user_id ){
     if ( $user_id == '0' ) {
      return ;
   }
   
          
           if(isset($_POST['selectitem']) == 'apple') {
     
          $fruitcategory = 'fruit, fruits';
          update_user_meta( $user_id, 'product_category_type', $fruitcategory );
          
} else if(isset($_POST['selectitem']) == 'bread') {
   
          $foodcategory = 'food, foods';
          update_user_meta( $user_id, 'product_category_type', $foodcategory );
       
} else if(isset($_POST['selectitem']) == 'milk') {

          $drinkcategory = "drink, drinks";
         
          update_user_meta( $user_id, 'product_category_type', $drinkcategory );
     
} else {
     echo "error";
}
       
}
```

I am using a shortcode to display the form plugin I am currently using. The form itself works fine in terms of submitting and the condition within the "if statement" seems to be working fine and storing the value of the selection within the user metakey, it's just the "elseif" statements which don't seem to be storing the values.

Update:

I've tried splitting the `elseif` statements in to regular `if` statements as oppose to using `elseif` and now it's getting the final value every time I select any option within the select dropdown list.

But one thing that is telling me is that it's finding the correct value for the last value in the if statement.

Is there any other alternative methods anyone could suggest for retrieving the values out of the select dropdown list other than the if/else statements?

I'm not too sure what's going wrong here! I've double checked my field values and they are correct. I've also tried `===` as oppose to `==` but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I'm having is that only the first condition seems to be
> working in terms of the metakey stored, the "elseif" conditions aren't
> storing the value of the metakey when selecting other options within
> the dropdown.

The reason of stated problem is `isset($_POST['selectitem']) == 'apple'` code. You're doing a comparison between the returned value from the `isset` check and your static string.

so `isset($_POST['selectitem'])` will either return `true` or `false`, in result you're doing `true == 'apple'` and since it's a loose comparison(==) then it will return true, hence your first if the condition is always valid because of explained comparison.

```
isset($_POST['selectitem']) && trim($_POST['selectitem']) === 'apple'
```

it will be the correct code, first, you'll check for isste then you'll compare the posted with strict comparison(===)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the time you have taken to reply :-) Strangely, when I replace `==` with `===` on the first if statement, no metakey value is being stored at all, but it is being stored when I use `==`, but it's only working for the first if statement, I've tried adjusting all of `else if`  statements to `===` instead of `==` and it's not storing any data in to the metakey at all including the first if statement.

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect the new strings attached to each variable (Within each conditional statement)

Comment: You can print the posted data and figureout which condition is not matching and what kind of data you're getting in `$_POST`